# Warning on starting hugo server

Tags: templates, hugo

I am getting below warning when I start hugo server.

Git Repo where I am getting the errors: https://github.com/jayrp11/mysite

```
WARN 2022/06/09 16:04:59 found no layout file for "HTML" for kind "page": You should create a template file which matches Hugo Layouts Lookup Rules for this combination.
WARN 2022/06/09 16:04:59 found no layout file for "HTML" for kind "page": You should create a template file which matches Hugo Layouts Lookup Rules for this combination.
WARN 2022/06/09 16:04:59 found no layout file for "HTML" for kind "taxonomy": You should create a template file which matches Hugo Layouts Lookup Rules for this combination.
WARN 2022/06/09 16:04:59 found no layout file for "HTML" for kind "taxonomy": You should create a template file which matches Hugo Layouts Lookup Rules for this combination.
```

I can see the site is working fine. I am able to see the contents but I am not sure why those errors on console?

I confirmed that these warnings are from p1.md and p2.md files. I am new to hugo and trying to create a page with bit of summary content for each child page. Is better way to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in your config file:

```
disableKinds:
- taxonomy
```

And add a single.html and a list.html in your `layouts/_default/` directory.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same warning. It turns out that I use a theme and haven't install it before `hugo server`.

In my case, I use git submodule. So I have to run:

```bash
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

at project's root directory.

Hopefully, it can give you some help.